# Upgrade mint from command line: "Do not edit this file manually"

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, upgrade

In the past, the method I've used for upgrading linux mint from the command line has been to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` by hand, then  `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get upgrade`. In the version I'm currently trying to upgrade (17.2), sources.list doesn't exist, and official-package-repositories.list has the following warning in a comment on its first line:

```
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.
```

I assume Software Sources is the GUI front end.

What is now the correct way to do an upgrade from the command line? If I edit the file manually, will it not work? Will things break?

Comment: Please do not understand this comment as offensive, that is not my intent.  But, since you are upgrading your linux mint a second time, it might be time to switch to a rolling forward distribution or at least a distribution that packs more functionality with a single major release (akin of Debian).

Comment: @grochmal What's wrong with upgrading an installation multiple times??? (Asking from an installation that's gone etch→lenny→squeeze→wheezy→jessie — the chain would be longer if I hadn't started from scratch when I got an amd64 machine.)

Comment: @Gilles - just had bad (probably isolated) experiences upgrading "user friendly" distros, really.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is not tested, I consulted a colleague at work who uses Mint (and he did swear at me to use the GUI).

#### 17.2 -> 17.3

First of all you must be at Mint 17.3 to upgrade to Mint 18.  So let's do that first.  Mint has an upgrade manager (I know you are asking about how to do it from the command line but have [earlier questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162195/what-is-the-command-line-equivalent-to-mintupdate-for-linux-mint) about the command line and it seems that it is just too arcane/esoteric, but keep reading below for a couple of possible hacks).  In the upgrade manager you should be able to do `Edit->Upgrade to Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa`.

And that's as far as we go with the "read the docs, be a civic citizen, and use Mint the way the developers want you to use it".  We can be more adventurous than that. If you look at the code for the [Mint upgrade tool](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintupdate/blob/master/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/mintUpdate.py) (the GUI code), you can see some interesting things:

```
    rel_edition = 'unknown'
    rel_codename = 'unknown'
    if os.path.exists("/etc/linuxmint/info"):
        with open("/etc/linuxmint/info", "r") as info:
            for line in info:
                line = line.strip()
                if "EDITION=" in line:
                    rel_edition = line.split('=')[1].replace('"', '').split()[0]
                if "CODENAME=" in line:
                    rel_codename = line.split('=')[1].replace('"', '').split()[0]

    rel_path = "/usr/share/mint-upgrade-info/%s" % rel_codename
    if os.path.exists(rel_path):
        with open(os.path.join(rel_path, "info")) as f:
            config = dict([line.strip().split("=") for line in f])
        if rel_edition.lower() in config['editions']:
            rel_target = config['target_name']
            relUpgradeMenuItem = Gtk.ImageMenuItem(Gtk.STOCK_PREFERENCES)
            relUpgradeMenuItem.set_use_stock(True)
            relUpgradeMenuItem.set_image(Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("mintupdate-release-upgrade", Gtk.IconSize.MENU))
            relUpgradeMenuItem.set_label(_("Upgrade to %s") % rel_target)

# ...

def open_rel_upgrade(self, widget):
    os.system("/usr/bin/mint-release-upgrade &")
```

We see that you should have a file called `/etc/linuxmint/info` which should contain a couple of lines similar to this:

```
EDITION=Mint 17.2 Yay
CODENAME=17.2-yay
```

(note that I do not have a Mint running so I am guessing there)

Based on that you should have a file called:

```
/usr/share/mint-upgrade-info/17.2-yay
```

Which should then contain:

```
target_name=Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
```

If all that is in place you should be able to do:

```
/usr/bin/mint-release-upgrade
```

And that should do the work.

#### Extra notes

You will probably need to perform some updates after booting into the new system.  Mint upgrade do not perform kernel or GRUB updates, so you will need to do:

```
sudo apt-get update linux-kernel-generic
sudo update-grub
```

Also, the int upgrade page advises to disable the screensaver during the update:

> It is recommended to disable the screensaver before upgrading. If the screensaver activates during the upgrade and you’re unable to log back in, switch to console with CTRL+ALT+F1, log in, and type “killall cinnamon-screensaver” (or “killall mate-screensaver” in MATE). Use CTRL+ALT+F7 or CTRL+ALT+F8 to get back to your session.

References:

- [Mint blog on update to 17.3](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2955)

---

#### 17.3 -> 18

First important point from the Mint Release notes:

> The KDE edition isn't upgradable (Linux Mint 18 KDE will use a new and different desktop called Plasma).

If you are using KDE, you're screwed, thanks Mint guys (just kidding, they added Plasma, so they needed to sacrifice something).

On the bright side the 17.3 -> 18 migration can be performed with the `mintupgrade` command line tool (that's not the `mintupdate` GUI tool, yeah the similarity in the names is confusing).  You can simply perform (as root):

```
apt install mintupgrade
mintupgrade check
mintupgrade download
mintupgrade upgrade
```

The `mintupgrade check` is an interactive step, which will ask you several questions.

The Mint documentation on the 17.3 -> 18 is actually pretty thorough and well explained, and worth reading.

References:

- [Mint community post on how to upgrade to Linux Mint 18 (a very good read)](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2316)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you can use `add-apt-repository` to add repositories. So in Mint -- I guess. From my perspective its absolutely viable to manually edit the `sources.list` but in some cases you will end up importing gpg-keys for the repositories manually too...

Comment: This is helpful and interesting, but sketchy.