# Confusion between Xenial and Sylvia in Unattended-upgrades

Tags: linux-mint, unattended-upgrades

I am trying to get Unattended-upgrades to work on my Linux Mint 18.3 (Sylvia) system, without success. My `etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` is standard:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
etc.
```

but when I run it it never finds any upgrades. Here’s the output of `sudo unattended-upgrades -d`

```
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['o=LinuxMint,a=sylvia', 'o=LinuxMint,a=sylvia-security']
Checking: unrar ([<Origin component:'multiverse' archive:'xenial-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'multiverse' archive:'xenial-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'security.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
fetch.run() result: 0
blacklist: []
whitelist: []
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

But, I have an upgrade listed in the GUI Update Manager, for unrar-nonfree. The first line of the changelog is `unrar-nonfree (1:5.3.2-1+deb9u1build0.16.04.1) xenial-security; urgency=medium`

How can I make Unattended-upgrades look for xenial upgrades, as well as sylvia?

Comment: Mint 18.x is based on Ubuntu 16.04 = Xenial so this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be not to use Unattended-upgrades on Mint.

Mint 18.2 and 18.3 include `mintupdate-tool`. In Mint 19, it is enhanced and renamed to `mintupdate-cli` as noted at https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=274526&p=1504252&hilit=unattended+upgrade+18#p1504252

I could not find any documentation, but this answer is very helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417942

`mintupdate-tool` uses the same preferences as in Update Manager, so you can simply do:

```
sudo mintupdate-tool upgrade
```

or add it to root’s cron.